# Adding values to existing cursor SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cursor

Is it possible to add values to cursor that already exists? while processing it (between begin and fetch next)??

edit 1:

I have a list of values in cursor. On this I am doing some logic and selecting few records.I would need to perform same logic on the newly selected records which may lead to other new records and so on. basically a recursive drill down.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do instead of how you've decided to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to increase the number of records returned from the cursor query while the cursor is iterating through its resultset?

Comment: @DeadZone not from the cursor query. I want to apply same logic applied to cursor , to be applied to the newly selected data.That's why i want to add them to cursor.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i have edited the question to clarify your point.